# Looking for javascript code that will let me switch true to false after a few miliseconds

Tags: javascript, if-statement, wait

I'm pretty new at javascript and coding in general so I may be using some of the phrasing but I hope that you can understand what I'm looking for.

I was simply wondering what the easiest way would be to code a true statement switching to a false statement after a few miliseconds.

```
    if (ship.shooting = true) {
        (what would go here?)
        ship.shooting = false;
    }
```

The statement above obviously does not work because as soon as the statement gets read as true it instantly gets flipped back to false. So is there a line of code I could put in between there that basically says to wait?

If it's true. -->
Wait one second. -->
Then set it to false.

I hope that my question makes sense and thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to wait one second and not do anything else, or do you want the condition to flip after one second, but allow other things to happen in-the-meantime (like accepting user input from the keyboard, drawing pictures on the screen, etc.)?

Comment: Other things are still allowed to happen during this time. It's just that the specific function 'ship.shooting' needs to remain true for one second or less before being switched to false.

Comment: Sounds like you are making a game. Great! Usually, game-loops keep track of passed time inbetween ticks as "delta time" (`dt`, `delta`, `deltaTime`, or similar), which updating objects may use. This makes your game run more reliable, as using asynchronous methods like Promises or `setTimeout()` might not _always_ perform as expected. Say, a tick starts at almost 1s, and at the time of updating this `ship`, 1s has passed. It could have been flipped by that time, but it shouldn't have, because other ships that fired in the same tick, but updated earlier, didn't get this advantage.

Answer (score 3):

You may declare the function this code is in as async and await a Promise like this:

```
async function doStuff(){
  ...
  if (ship.shooting = true) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    ship.shooting = false;
  }
}
```

The Code in this example would stop execution and continue after 1000 milliseconds.

You can also use setTimeout() if the function is not supposed to stop execution:

```
function doStuff(){
  ...
  if (ship.shooting = true) {
    setTimeout(() => {    
      ship.shooting = false;
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```